# Changing background of listbox item on mouse over

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-7

I have my listbox items styled like this:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#007acc"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="#007acc"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="WhiteSmoke"/>            
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,2,5,2"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
</Style>
```

But I can't figure out, how to change the background color for a listboxitem when a mouse cursor is hovering over it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve the effect you desire, use a [Trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.trigger.aspx) in the style operating on the *ListBoxItem's* [IsMouseOver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ismouseover.aspx) property. *IsMouseOver* is a boolean property which is automatically set to `true` when the mouse is over the ListBox item. (Read the [MSDN documentation for IsMouseOver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ismouseover.aspx) to get a better understanding of how this property works.)

The XAML of the style with the trigger would look like this:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    ...

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

(If you check the [MSDN documentation for Trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.trigger.aspx) you will notice that the example i gave here does not look much different from the example given in the documentation...)

Answer (score -1):

Use the `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseenter(v=vs.110).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseleave(v=vs.110).aspx

On the `MouseEnter` event, change the background color. On `MouseLeave`, revert to the "normal" color. This should give the effect you want.